# Xcode's Instruments crashes when recording starts with Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode, instruments

Whenever I hit 'record' on the instruments tool, it 
crashes with the error: "NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: Fatal, partial event too large (4198344)" This only happens when testing with my phone (iPhone 5s, iOS 10.3.2(14F89)), running instruments with simulator works fine. I did have to copy over the 10.3.2 files from the Xcode beta into my 'DeviceSupport' folder. Could that be the ultimate root source, and is there a way around it if it is?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Xcode 8.2.1? The current version of Xcode, 8.3.3, has better support for iOS 10.3. I suggest either updating Xcode or downgrading your phone to iOS 10.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode 8.3.3 works on macOS 10.12 or greater and my macbook is 10.11.6, leaving me with 8.2.1. I'll try downgrading my phone to 10.2 and see if that helps